# How do I get files from zipped folder and encode and save them to database without extracting the files?

Tags: c#, .net, database, encode

Server has almost 50 GBs of zipped files. I need a best approach to extract files from these zipped folder and base 64 encode them and saved them into Database as blob. I wish not to extract the whole zipped folder if possible.
Please guide me.

Comment: Look at the (second) example given in the ZipArchive documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.8. But instead of letting the (uncompressed) stream of a Zip file entry being written to a file (as the example does), just [take the stream object of the uncompressed ZIP entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open) and do with it as you please (like read from it, hand it over to a base64 encoder of your choice, challenge it to a drinking contest, etc...)

Comment: Note, that technically you'll have to unzip the data eventually - unless you want to store zipped content in the database. You can however do that "in memory", as @elgonzo suggested, thus not incurring the overhead of first writing files to disk that you then would re-read anyway.

Comment: I try and let you know if I stuck. Thank you.

Comment: What you're asking for is really a combination of three discrete operations: extracting compressed files to memory, base64 encoding a stream/array, and saving a base64 string to a database.  Have you looked at existing questions related to those individual operations?  Which operations have you tried implementing and which are you having problems with?  Do you have enough RAM to store 233% of the size of the largest file within a compressed archive (binary file + base64 file + base64 overhead)?  Also, it'd be helpful if you'd indicate what database you're using.

Comment: I was stuck in other task. I have not yet started this yet. I am using MS Sql Db. I am open up for any advise. I have never dealt with such task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace zipStream
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var file = File.OpenRead(@"YOUR-REMOTE-FILE-NAME");
            ZipArchive ar = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in ar.Entries)
            {
                using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Byte[] inArray = new Byte[(int)entry.Length];
                        Char[] outArray = new Char[(int)((entry.Length + 10) * 2)];
                        stream.Read(inArray, 0, (int)entry.Length);
                        Convert.ToBase64CharArray(inArray, 0, inArray.Length, outArray, 0);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Processed {entry.Name}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        var msg = e.Message;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to process {entry.Name}");
                        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                    }
                }
                // at this point you have your file content in outArray variable
                // you can find some guidance on writing blobs to a db here:
                // https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ashush/working-with-binary-large-objects-blobs/
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into the situation where there are inner zip files inside some zip files. How do I handle the situation?